# How to wrap a component using react-router-redux

Tags: react-router-redux

I upgraded the project I'm working on by switching from react-router-redux to connected-router-react. But there is a shared component used to handle errors. This one is still using react-router-redux. Now I'm getting an error "Could not find "store" in either the context or props of..."
Is there a way to wrap the error component in order to keep it usable ?
Thanks